# how to get insert_id using mysqli prepare statements

Tags: php, mysqli, last-insert-id

How can I get the insert_id of the last record using mysqli prepare statement, for example following?

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name) values (?)")
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 11):

`$new_id = $this->mysqli->insert_id;` (after `$stmt->execute()`)

Answer (score 2):

[mysqli->insert_id](http://us.php.net/mysqli_insert_id)